# How can we Monitor DDOS Attacks using Stackdriver Monitoring in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I have already enabled VPC flow logs but what could be the best filters to use to capture DDOS attacks.I know GCP provided Cloud Armour for DDOS Attack prevention  but i want to set monitoring on  Stackdriver .

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific filter to capture DDoS attacks as such.
In Stackdriver Monitoring, you can select:

Resource type: GCE VM Instance
Metric: Received packets

with a trial and error to find exactly what you want but rate, delta, and 99th percentile should all be viable options.